# Spivak's curious thoughts about the action of permutations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, differential-geometry, permutations, group-actions

Here is an excerpt of Spivak's Differential Geometry.

[image]

What I do not understand is why he believes $\sigma \cdot (\rho \cdot v) = (\rho\sigma) \cdot v$. Since $\sigma$ and $\rho$ are elements of the symmetric group, they are permutations and thus form a group action which permutes tuples - in being a group action, they must satisfy $\sigma \cdot (\rho \cdot v) = (\sigma\rho) \cdot v$. For the obviously non-abelian symmetric group, it's easy to find examples where these are not equal.

Of course I don't think the book has such a glaring error in it, but I just don't see how it could be true. If you "just did it", you'd have $$\sigma\cdot(\rho\cdot (v_1\ldots v_k)) = \sigma\cdot(v_{\rho(1)}\ldots v_{\rho(k)}) = (v_{\sigma(\rho(1))}\ldots v_{\sigma(\rho(k))})$$
Which is clearly not always the same as his result. He says stuff about how if the $v$'s have their indices running in some different order, but who cares? $\sigma\cdot(v_3, v_2, v_1,\ldots ) = (v_{\sigma(3)}, v_{\sigma(2)}, v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots)$, right? What's the problem??

Comment: Look at $S_3$, have $\sigma$ be the cycle $(321)$ (move everything to the left). Then $\sigma(v_2,v_3,v_1)=(v_3,v_1,v_2)\neq(v_{\sigma(2)},v_{\sigma(3)},v_{\sigma(1)})=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$. It is important that the action of $S_n$ is on an ordered set. If you give everything a number, there is obviously a standard order, and given an order there is a numbering of the set. But having the permutations act on the numbering is different from having it act on the ordered set if the numbering differs from the ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to think about sequences $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k)$ here. Your way is to treat them as bijective functions $f:\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}\to \{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ in which case the symmetric group acts by left composition, meaning $(\sigma\cdot f)(v_i)=\sigma(f(v_i))$. In that case it is easy to see that $\sigma\cdot (\rho\cdot f)=(\sigma\rho)\cdot f$.

Spivak's way, however, is to treat the sequences as functions $g:\{1,2,\ldots,k\}\to \{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ where the symmetric group acts by *right* composition, meaning $(\sigma\cdot g)(i)=g(\sigma(i))$. You can verify that in that case we indeed have that $\sigma\cdot (\rho\cdot g)=(\rho\sigma)\cdot g$.